# EXCEL VBA Attempting to loop through chart series (lines, bars) and dynamically change based on RGB codes referenced in my spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through the lines in an excel chart and change the colors and widths of the lines based off predetermined RGB codes that I have referenced in my spreadsheet.

I tried changing how the colors are stored as variable (integer, variant, colorformat)

```
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 10").Chart

    'loop through series in chart to format lines

    Dim ser As Series
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6 As ColorFormat

    color1 = RGB(Range("B8"), Range("c8"), Range("d8"))
    color2 = RGB(Range("B9"), Range("c9"), Range("d9"))
    color3 = RGB(Range("B10"), Range("c10"), Range("d10"))
    color4 = RGB(Range("B11"), Range("c11"), Range("d11"))

    i = 1
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
        ser.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = "color" & i
        i = i + 1
    Next ser
```

I expected the lines in my chart to change to the RGB codes I had laid out in my spreadsheet but various runtime errors returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the following issues:

1. The [`RGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) function returns a `Long`, which should be the type of each color.
2. You need to repeat the type when declaring variables, otherwise they are actually `Variant`s: `Dim color1 as Long, color2 as Long, color3 as Long, color4 as Long`.
3. The result of `color & i` is a `String`, not the variables you intend to work with.

All that said, you don't need the color variables here, just a simple loop, something roughly like this (can be beautified but you get the idea):

```
Sub asdf()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 10").Chart

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
        cht.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = _
            RGB(Range("B7").Offset(i).Value, Range("C7").Offset(i).Value, Range("D7").Offset(i).Value)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Sample Chart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and concise response. Do you have a good way to run this code by selecting the active chart instead of having to retype "Chart x" every time I want to apply this code to a new chart? I tried changing ChartObjects("Chart 10") to ActiveChart but it's returning a run time error '438'.

Comment: I am new to the site. If you have a moment will you take a look at my follow up question above.

Comment: Untested, but try `Set cht = ActiveChart`